# SQL Query to compare the first X characters of 2 fields in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table named 'Parts'. I am looking to create a SQL query that compares the first X characters of two of the fields, let's call them 'PartNum1' and 'PartNum2'. For example, I would like to return all records from 'Parts' where the first 6 characters of 'PartNum1' equals the first 6 characters of 'PartNum2'.

Parts

| PartNum1 | PartNum2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 12345600 |
| 12388888 | 12345000 |
| 12000000 | 14500000 |

the query would only return row 1 since the first 6 characters match. MS SQL Server 2017 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I have searched and can't seem to find anything that specifically addresses this situation.

Comment: What about `like`?

Comment: or something like `where left(t.PartNum1, 6) = left(t.PartNum2, 6)`? Here "t" is an alias for your table.

Comment: you have partnum fields as it or varchar ?

Comment: PartNum fields are varchar. I used SMor's answer above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are strings, use `left()`:

```
left(partnum1, 6) = left(partnum2, 6)
```

This would be appropriate in a `where`, `on`, or `case` expression.  Note that using `left()` would generally prevent the use of indexes.  If this is for a `join` and you care about performance, you might want to include a computed column with the first six characters.

Comment: Even though SMor provided the answer in a comment, I appreciate the explanation and additional information here so marking this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. I am assuming datatype as integer. You can set size of varchar based on length of fields.

```
select * 
from Parts
WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(PartNum1 AS VARCHAR(max)), 1,6) = SUBSTRING(CAST(PartNum2 AS VARCHAR(max)), 1,6)
```

Comment: Agreed Sir. But I am not sure about size and data type. May be conversion not required. I have already raised question regarding datatype of these columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for simple division to see if the numerator matches for those partnumbers.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(partnum int, partnum2 int)

insert into @table values
(12345678,  12345600)
,(12388888, 12345000)
,(12000000, 14500000);

select * from @table where partnum/100 = partnum2/100
```

| partnum | partnum2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 12345600 |